# Unexpected/unwanted Gmail attachments when using GmailApp.sendEmail() containing a URL in text body

Tags: google-apps-script, email-attachments

I consider myself still new to Google Apps Script. I'm part of a small all volunteer organization that coordinates lifelong learning courses for our community.  For the past 5 semesters we've used Google Forms and Sheets to register persons.  Within Sheets we have an Apps Script extension function, onSpreadsheetSubmit(e), that emails a confirmation text email using GmailApp.sendEmail(). The script is definitely amateurish, but it works reliably.

This semester, we set up Google Drive folders so attendees may access materials for each course. In our confirmation message we would like to add the course folder URL to the textBody.  When we test, the emails are successfully sent and the textBody is received as expected, but somehow unwanted attachments of the course material folders (one for each course) are also being included.

I've been trying to locate a resource (document, forum, video, etc) where I can learn how to prevent the attachments from being included. I seem to be looking in all the wrong places. I would welcome and greatly appreciate any guidance.

Below is an example of where the link is placed for a single course. It gets joined with other content in the message:

```
    if (formValues[11].indexOf('Register') > -1) {
        wantCourse2 = 1 ;
        amountDue = amountDue + 35 ;
        numberOfCourses = numberOfCourses + 1 ;
        textBodyCourse2 = "\n \nCourse: 'The Life and Major Works of Edith Wharton,' with instructor xxxxx xxxxx. Starts Tuesday, March 7th and meets every subsequent Tuesday until April 11th (6 sessions.) Available in-person and online through Zoom.    \n Webinar ID: 865 5101 1111 \n Zoom link: https://us02web.zoom.us/j/86551011111 \n Should the professor at any point choose to make documents available to the class, they will be placed in a Google Drive folder, which can be accessed via this link: \n Documents: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1M3ZrLr2WPBSb69UbFZ29J4cTIABCDEFG?usp=sharing " ;
```

Below is the call:

```
GmailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, textBodyStart + textBodyPayment + textBodyCovid + textBodyCourses + textBodyClose, {name:"xxxx Registrar"});
```

In the first code example above , textBodyCourse2 ends up being combined with other courses the user may select and becomes a part of textBodyCourses that is seen in the GmailApp.sendEmail parameters in the second code snip.

Update:
After now having read the sent messages using several different email clients, the inclusion of the (unwanted) attachments seems to be limited to just the Gmail desktop application. Attachments do not appear in other clients such as Gmail's mobile version, Yahoo!, etc.  Thanks all.

Comment: I would guess that not using the attachments advanced parameter would solve that.  If you are already doing that then next best move might be to post your actual code so that we don't have to guess.

Comment: Hi and welcome. `textBodyCourse2` isn't even a parameter of your `GmailApp.sendEmail`. Would you please edit your question to include the whole script, a sample of the Form Response data, and an example of how an email should appear in a successful outcome.